# Brother DCP-7055 printer doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: printing, brother

I have Brother DCP-7055 and it doesn't print.

With default Ubuntu drivers installed "Printing completed" message appears but nothing happens.
After installing a driver from Brother's website printing tasks are added to the queue and sit there, nothing is being printed too.

I've installed the Brother driver from `linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz` file but I didn't go through the steps from Brother's [installation manual](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcp7055_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625)

How do I remove both printers and all drivers(files, packages) so that I can start over?

Answer (score 1):

I made it. I found and ran `uninstaller_DCP7055` file, then reinstalled drivers from manufacturer's file and chose 'NO' when asked "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?". Now the printer works.